# Using a class' constructor within a vector of the same type in C++

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor

Consider:

```
MyClass {
    //constructor
    MyClass()
    {}
.
.
.
};
```

Then, defining a vector of the same type

```
int main()
{
.
.
    vector<MyClass>myVector(12);
.
.
```

Is this allowed?

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    //an attempt to fill my vector with initialized MyClass objects.
    myVector[i] = MyClass(); //Calling constructor
}
```

OR:
(in the case of not defining a vector's size)

```
for(int i = 0; i < whatever; i++)
{
    //an attempt to fill my vector with initialized MyClass objects.
    myVector.push_back(MyClass()); //Calling constructor
}
```

If this is not allowed, what is an alternative for initializing class instances and storing them in a vector without using pointers? Is there such a thing?

Comment: Assuming MyClass is assignable, it will work, but it's pointless, because the vector automatically initializes its elements with their default constructor.

Comment: and what if there is no default constructor? (because I defined specific constructors)

Comment: @Gil In that case, `std::vector<MyClass> t(12, MyClass(0))` where you replace `0` with whatever default arguments you want should work.

Comment: Also look at std::vector<T>::emplace_back. You can pass parameters to the constructor this way.

Comment: @abellina isn't that a C++11's feature?

Comment: Indeed it is. Hopefully that is available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote is acceptable.

```
vector<MyClass>myVector(12);
```

will call default constructor of `MyClass` 12 times. So this is equivalent to

```
vector<MyClass>myVector;
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    myVector.push_back(MyClass());
}
```

Another variant you provided is slightly different

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++)
{
    myVector[i] = MyClass();
}
```

Here every element of vector is already initialized somehow. So when you do this, previous instance of `MyClass` will be removed (destructor will be called) and element will be assigned to new instance.

If you need make your default constructor private and initialize class with some value you have to use next aproach:

```
vector<MyClass>myVector(12, MyClass(some_value));
```

or as you already seen

```
vector<MyClass>myVector;
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    myVector.push_back(MyClass(some_value));
}
```

Comment: This almost answers my question! One little clarification if you will: if I define a class with no MyClass() (default) constructor, will I have a problem with initializing a vector within a class definition? Or, is it even possible to not define a MyClass() default constructor?
EDIT: I do however, define other constructors, such as MyClass(int) and MyClass(int, bool).

Comment: @GilDekel Yes, it's possible, you can make your default constructor private, for example, or don't specify it at all. If you have default constructor, but it's private, you can use ``vector`` within it without any restrictions. If you have no default constructor, you can still use ``vector`` like I described in my answer.